# How to get comments from Google Docs using the Google API

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I want to get comments from Google Docs using the Google Drive API.
Does anyone know if the Google Drive API (or other Google Apps Application APIs) supports retrieve commenting?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments/list

Answer (score 1):

Comments are not available via the API yet, but this is a common feature request that we are already evaluating. Stay tuned for updates soon.

Comment: Update: It was added https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments/list

Comment: Possible using python interface. For example, using the `printcomments` function of this python script I found over on github:  https://github.com/peterartman/GoogleDocCommentCollector/blob/c34f6623dc8c0481efb2d36e33ee54296a2f0025/commentcollector.py#L1

Comment: it boggles my mind why you didn't just make everything API first

Answer (score 1):

Comments are included for documents via download as text (using the DocumentsList API), although it may be difficult to distinguish comments from the regular text.

Comments for spreadsheets are included when the item is downloaded as html (again, using the DocumentsList API), but not included when downloaded in other formats.

Comments for presentations, drawings, and non-Google types are not readily available.

Comment: is this available yet?

Comment: I've not seen it, but I haven't worked with the Drive API for a while.

Comment: was trying to build a chrome extension whenever user clicks "resolve comment" button, copy all comments to doc and then resolve it. as of now when user resolves all comments are gone and not easily searchable with current UI.

Comment: If you're doing an extension, then you could add a JS hook to the "resolve" button, and then use the API to save the resolved comments as property metadata or some other invisible document section.